# How to define/declare a list of struct in python?

Tags: list, python-3.x, struct

I have the following code:

```
import os


test_list = [{"name" : "axi_rd_only_test", "seed" : 3}, {"name" : "axi_invalid_regs_test", "seed" : 5}]


os.popen("cd C:/raft/raftortwo/girobo2/ver/sim")

for test in test_list: 
    os.environ["MY_TEST_NAME"] = test.name
    os.environ["MY_TEST_SEED"] = test.seed
    os.system("vsim -c -do top_tb_simulate_reg.tcl")
```

I got the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\saritr\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\saritr\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 88, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/saritr/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/lib/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 490, in <module>
    @monkeypatch_method(pdb.Pdb, 'Pdb')
  File "C:/Users/saritr/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/lib/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 485, in decorator
    % (cls.__name__, old_ref))
KeyError: 'SpyderPdb._old_Pdb_user_return already exists.'
```

Should I define the struct's list differently?

Comment: one thing is for sure: `os.popen("cd C:/raft/raftortwo/girobo2/ver/sim")` does nothing. Use `os.chdir("C:/raft/raftortwo/girobo2/ver/sim")` to change the directory from within python. Maybe that's the issue. It is one of issues, for sure.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre -  actually `os.popen("cd C:/raft/raftortwo/girobo2/ver/sim")` does exactly what I want.

Comment: you mean: it does nothing, right?

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre -  No. It opens cmd, and move to the relevant dir.

Comment: OK. that doesn't change current python directory. I misunderstood, sorry.